# C, unknown conversion type character 0x20 in format [-Wformat=] error

Tags: c, printf

```
printf("\nThe largest dog is %c with a weight of %.2 kg\n", largetype, largest);
fprintf(outfile,"\The largest dog is %c with a weight of %.2f kg\n", largetype , largest);
printf("\nThe smallest dog is %c with a weight of %.2f kg\n", smalltype , smallest);
fprintf(outfile,"\nThe smallest dog is %c with a weight of %.2f kg\n", smalltype , smallest);
```

Hello,

So my C program is not compiling and it is showing me this error,

unknown conversion type character 0x20 in format [-Wformat=]

for the first 2 lines. 
Does anyone know what to do with this error?

Comment: `%.2 ` is a mistake, perhaps you meant `%.2f`

Comment: Thank you! It was just a missing f,

Comment: Character `0x20` is the space character -- specifically the one in `%.2 kg`, which needs to be `%.2f kg`.

Comment: A space can be used as a modifier before the width, precision, and conversion specifier to specify that a space should be used for non negative values where the sign would go for negative values. For example `printf("|% d|% d|%+d|", 1, -1, 1);` prints `| 1|-1|+1|`.  Few programmers know this...

Comment: @chqrlie: Yes, but the space is a *flag*, and it has to precede any field width. Reference: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 7.21.6.1 paragraphs 4 and 6.

Comment: @KeithThompson: OK I wrote *a modifier before the width, precision, and conversion specifier*, my bad, the kosher term is *flag* and indeed it must appear before the width if any.

Comment: @chqrlie: Not criticizing, just expanding a bit on what you write.

Answer (score 4):

In your first row

```
printf("\nThe largest dog is %c with a weight of %.2 kg\n", largetype, largest);
```

You're using `%.2`, but you're not specifying the type, that's what's throwing the conversion error.  You should use `%.2f` instead, just like in the row below.

```
printf("\nThe largest dog is %c with a weight of %.2f kg\n", largetype, largest);
```

Comment: Please do not encourage questions which just include an obvious typo by providing an answer.

Comment: There is a reason this onehas been closed. Not every question is OT. Try asking why clouds are white.